# How to Connect PvD(Physx Visual Debugger) to another PC over a local network

Tags: c++, debugging, physx

First of all I want to ask is this even possible?
(I feel like it is because its connecting through TCP/IP network socket)

Im trying to setup my PvD so I can see the frames of a physx scene that is being run on another computer.

Ive tried using my own local ip-address and the same port:5425 
(thats the port the physx docs recommend you use).

When you create a socket for the PvD it wants a ip-address, port and a timoutInMs.

`PxPvdTransport* transport = PxDefaultPvdSocketTransportCreate("LOCAL_IP", 5425, 10);`
(Ive changed the timeout to 10000(10sec) and it still wont connect)

Could it be that my timeout is to small, im using the wrong ip-address or the wrong port?

Here you also have the docs for PvD https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/3.3.4/Manual/VisualDebugger.html

Ive read it all and they dont really specifiy if its possible to do what I want to do. Or im just bad at reading if I missed some curcial information from that doc

Im not sure ive covered everything that people need to know about my question but if you need more information tell me and I'lle gladly provide more.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was, I needed to open the port on my firewall.
I'lle keep this question if someone else encouters the same problem.

Comment: I was about to suggest checking your firewall after reading your question; but you have already posted this answer in regards to that...